# ARKit 3.0 – People Occlusion with Motion Capture

Tags: swift, augmented-reality, arkit, realitykit

I am trying to load both `people occlusion` and `motion capture` on the same app.

Since `ARBodyTrackingConfiguration` does not support `personSegmentationWithDepth`, I am creating 2 ARViews, giving each a different configuration (`ARWorldTrackingConfiguration` and `ARBodyTrackingConfiguration`).

The problem is that for some reason only one of the delegates callback is fired, and no depth data is available.

What am I doing wrong here?

Is it not OK to have more than one ARSession live at the same time?

Comment: You need to choose one or the other. `ARWorldTrackingConfiguration` with person segmentation will give an `ARBody2D` on the `ARFrame` which will give you less detailed but some of the same kind of information you get from an `ARBodyTrackingConfiguration`.

Answer (score 1):

In ARKit 4.0 both features can be run simultaneously. However they are both CPU intensive.

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    
    guard ARBodyTrackingConfiguration.isSupported
    else { fatalError("MoCap is supported on devices with A12 and higher") }
    
    guard ARBodyTrackingConfiguration.supportsFrameSemantics(
                                               .personSegmentationWithDepth)
    else { fatalError("People occlusion is not supported on this device.") }
        
    let config = ARBodyTrackingConfiguration()
    config.frameSemantics = .personSegmentationWithDepth
    config.automaticSkeletonScaleEstimationEnabled = true
    arView.session.run(config, options: [])
}
```